# Sorry! 7 Card splitting between two pawns

Tags: sorry

My husband seems to think on a 7 (where you can split between two pawns) you can split the number between someone else’s pawns as well as yours. He thinks that just because it says “any” pawn.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only move your own pawns. The rules don’t specify this under the description of the 7 card, but they actually don’t specify that for any number. The “3”, for example, simply says “move one pawn forward 3 spaces”. The “1” says “either start a pawn out OR move one pawn forward one space”. The rulebook as a whole always just assumes that you only ever move your own pieces without ever stating it. “Move a pawn” and “move any pawn” are grammatically the same meaning.

Comment: And see https://gamerules.com/rules/sorry-board-game/ for another version of the rules that specifies "split the move between two of your pawns".